# Make Bibliography part and Conclusions part appear in the same page

Tags: bibliographies, page-breaking

I have a part of the document where the **Conclusions** and then the **Bibliography** are exposed, just as I show here:

[image]

**Conclusions** is introduced with this code:

```
\chapter*{Conclusions}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusions}
\label{conclu}

Here we outline the principal conclusions of the work presented:
```

**Bibliography** is introduced with this code:

```
(final line of the written Conclusions)

\clearpage  
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografía}   %%% This two lines are added in order that the Bibliography part appear in the index as "Bibliografía", and the page.


\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{./bibliography}
```

The `clearpage` followed by the `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografía}` is necessary in order to make **Bibliografía** appear in the index, with its page.

I would like the `Bibliografía` part start just after the last line of Conclusions, and also having **Bibliografía..........page** in the index.

How should the upper codes be modified in order to achieve this ?

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\parindent 1 true cm
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}    
\usepackage[longnamesfirst,super]{natbib} 
\setcitestyle{square}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\pagestyle{fancy}                                        
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter .\ #1}{}}             
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection .\ #1}{}}
\lhead{\nouppercase}
\rhead{\nouppercase}
\fancyhead[LE]{{\sf \leftmark}}                             
\fancyhead[RE]{}
\fancyhead[RO]{{\sf \rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{}                                                
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}                                           
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{}                                                         
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}                                
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\captionsetup{font={small}}
\begin{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. As such, your example is neither complete, but contains a lot of stuff not needed at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\clearpage` must be `\relax`ed in order to prevent the \clearpage call of `\bibliography`.

The command `\addcontentsline` should appear in almost any case after the sectioning command, i.e. `\chapter*` or `\bibliography`. If `hyperref` is used, there should be a `\phantomsection` before the sectioning command.

Hint: You can use `\bibname` in order to use the name of your bibliography in the corresponding language (Spanish in your case) automatically.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\parindent 1 true cm
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

%%% Other packages here

\usepackage{blindtext}%

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Blabla}
\blindtext
\nocite{Lamport94}
\phantomsection    
\chapter*{Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion}

\phantomsection
\let\Origclearpage\clearpage
\let\clearpage\relax
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{bib}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\let\clearpage\Origclearpage
\end{document}
```

[image]