# No page break for \listoffigures with scrreprt

Tags: page-breaking

I include three lists: `\listoffigures`, `\listoftables`, and `\lstlistoflistings`. However each list on a new page. I don't want to have a page break after each list but to list all three on one page.

After some googling I found out that this behavior is connected to the document class. My documents is using `scrreprt` and I cannot (don't want to) change the type.

If I'm not mistaken I need to rewrite / overwrite these commands to remove the page breaks. But I don't know how to do this.

Comment: The page break is due to a `\clearpage` which is placed inside the commands `\listoffigures` etc. You have to relax `\clearpage`. See the answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187602/make-bibliography-part-and-conclusions-part-appear-in-the-same-page/187605#187605, especially at the end of the document, just replace the `\printbibliography` with your `\listof....` commands and omit the `\addcontentsline` in it.

Comment: Or see the approach here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162681 (and please add an MWE, as always).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way is to relax `\clearpage`, such that is doing nothing when called.

Other possibilities (not in here): Redefine the commands `\listoftables` etc. and remove the `\clearpage` in there or use `etoolbox` package in order to patch them or the answer given in the link in LariFaRi's comment.

Of course, the content lists will not fit on one page if there are a lot entries in them.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\let\LaTeXStandardClearpage\clearpage
\let\clearpage\relax  % Do nothing when a \clearpage command appears 
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings

\let\clearpage\LaTeXStandardClearpage % Return to the old definition


\chapter{First}

\begin{figure}

\caption{Dummy figure}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{table}

\caption{Dummy table}

\end{table}





\chapter{Second}
\section{First}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C, caption={Hello World in C}]
#include <stdio.h>

\int main( void )
{
 printf("Hello World\n");
 return(0);
}


\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]